# OpenGL Video Memory Usage

Tags: c++, memory, opengl, profiling, video-memory

is there an API or profiler application that can track the video memory usage of my application?

I am using C++/OpenGL on Windows, but I am open to suggestions on other platforms as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS X you have *OpenGL Profiler.app*, which comes with the Developer Tools (on the OS DVD or from http://developer.apple.com)

On Windows you could try [gDEBugger](http://www.gremedy.com/products.php?sdk) - a good commercial OpenGL Profiling tool.